# Does :not() negation accept descendant selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've been using the `:not()` pseudo-class to style things without the need to override it with a second unnecessary declaration to undo the first one,
but now I came across a weird behaviour where Safari accepts descendant selectors within the `:not()`, but Chrome doesn't.

I used something like `a:not(.blue a)`.

I searched for answers, but I still don't fully understand the reason.
Are descendant selectors really allowed by the spec?

Here's a demo:

```css
a:not(.blue a) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div><a>this one should be in red</a></div>
<div class="blue"><a>this one shouldn't</a></div>
```

http://codepen.io/oscarmarcelo/pen/YqboQJ?editors=1100

Comment: Also I believe a:not(.blue a) would be excluding `<a>` elements with class `blue` that also have children `<a>` elements. What you're expecting is parent selector behavior inside that `:not()` selector.

Comment: @TylerH: a:not(.blue a) represents a elements that are not descendants of .blue elements.

Comment: @BoltClock That's unique and different from everything else :-/

Comment: @TylerH: It's not. The subject of every CSS selector you've worked with has always been the rightmost selector. It's no different here. The subject of the selector argument is a.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm referring more or less to the whole `:not()` logic behaving that way, rather than this one particular case.

Comment: The duplicate question has good material on my the :not selector works this way.

Comment: is using this `div:not(.blue) a` out of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation), the answer would be NO. The `:not()` notation accepts only *simple selectors*.

> [**6.6.7. The negation
>   pseudo-class**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)
>
> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking
>   a *simple selector* (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its
>   argument.

*What is a simple selector?*

From [selector syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn):

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

Nothing about a descendant selector.

***HOWEVER***, in [Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation), `:not()` accepts *complex selectors*, which would include descendant combinators. Browser support is still quite weak for this specification.

Comment: So, you mean that `a:not(.blue a)` is allowed in CSS4?

Comment: That is correct. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation