# Correct use of CSS :not selector for excluding element when in particular container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am styling a series of pages of which I have no control of their markup, and it is presenting some unique challenges. The styles are based on a design mockup that I was given and therefore there are instances of- for example- h2 elements that must look different than other particular h2 elements in order for the design to be adhered to.

Currently, I am trying to apply some styling that should affect *most* h2 elements, but not h2 elements which appear within a div with the class "block". How would the CSS selector look in this case? I went out on a limb and tried this, but was correct in assuming it wasn't quite right.

```
h2:not(.block h2) {
   ~styling for main h2 elements~
}
.block h2 {
  ~separate styling for h2 elements within .block div~
}
```

Can someone shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the order and putting .block h2 above, as the the first one doesn't know what .block h2 is when it's loaded first.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the HTML and the actual styles that need to be applied?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work this way, the selector inside `:not()` must be a simple selector. This means that descendent selectors like `.block h2` won't work.

Comment: You're really better off if you don't jump through hoops trying to avoid styles for "general" h2 affecting those h2 inside div.block, but rather simply __overwrite__ the _general_ styles that you don't like for `div.block h2` with the _specific_ property values that you do want those to have.

Comment: There's a canonical for this somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
h2 {...}

.block h2 {...}
```

Comment: Yep, simple but this seems to work fine. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to apply some styling that should affect most `h2` elements, but not `h2` elements which appear within a div with the class `block`.

You haven't indicated the level where the `h2` exists within the div. So here are a few options, if you want to use the `:not()` pseudo-class.

*If the `h2` is one level in:*

```css
div:not(.block) h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <h2>with block class</h2>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>without block class</h2>
</div>
```

*If the `h2` is two levels in:*

```css
div:not(.block) div h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <h2>with block class</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <h2>without block class</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

*If the `h2` is three levels in:*

```css
div:not(.block) div div h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>with block class</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>without block class</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and so on...

Also keep in mind that `:not()`, as it currently exists in most browsers, only accepts [*simple selectors*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37305971/3597276) as an argument.

Your example...

```
h2:not(.block h2) {
   ~styling for main h2 elements~
}
```

... will fail in most browsers because the argument contains a *complex selector* (created by a descendant combinator, in this case).

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37305971/3597276

Comment: This answer *might* be a good solution depending on the OP's html (which he hasn't provided).